# Icons don't remain on the desktop - Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, desktop-icons

I need some help: I cannot put any icon on the desktop, when I try the icon simply doesn't remain on it (there is a little animation where the icon becomes little and it 'goes' towards the Lubuntu logo left-down).

- Lubuntu 18.04.2 32bit
- Fujitsu Amilo L7320

I use Lubuntu 18.04.2 on several computers, this is the only one that it has that strange behaviour.

Thaks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have a totally empty desktop: I would like to add desktop shortcuts for Firefox, Thunderbird....

Comment: No, it doesn't work... it cannot finish the operation and it gives an error message. Anyway, I think you have found the origin of the problem: I've noticed that the desktop tab in pcmanfm has got some strange symbols (interrogative points, some numbers), not the 'desktop' writing as usual...

Comment: What error? What symbols? Examples might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, you are right, it would be more simple if I could post a screenshot... Translating from italian, the error is: it's impossible to open the file [here the path for the "file.desktop"].

Comment: Oh, I've just noted that the path of the desktop in pcmanfm is very strange: /home/[mypcname]/N   --> what is 'N'? In all my other computers I have here 'desktop' and not 'N'...

Comment: Well now that's curious indeed. What is the value of `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` in `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`? It *should* be `$HOME/Desktop`. I can't imagine you would just casually go in and change that, but it sounds like you have it set to `$HOME/N`.

Comment: here is the whole file: XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Scaricati"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Modelli"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Pubblici"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documenti"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Musica"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Immagini"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Video"

Comment: I didn't change any value, but effectively you are right! Now I try to change the value... obviously, in my case, in italian (Scrivania)

Comment: Ok, just modified into 'Scrivania' (desktop in italian), done a reboot and... voilà! Icons now are on the desktop!! It's a mystery how it could happen, anyway... thank you very much!

Comment: I would mark this as 'closed' and I would like to upvote your answer: how can I do?

Comment: Real answer provided so you can mark it as the right answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the value of `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` in `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is set to `$HOME/Desktop` to ensure the desktop functions as expected.

Comment: ok, voted! but my reputation is under 15, so a message says that my vote is recorded but not publicly displayed... thanks again!

Comment: That works. Thanks and be well!